# change script from selected to incoming mail

Tags: vba, outlook

Basic question - I have a script that saves attachments from selected emails in outlook, I want it to save the attachments automatically when they come in instead (I'll create a rule in outlook to run the script when an email comes in), any help would be appreciated!

```
Public Sub script()

Dim saveFolder As String
Dim objAtt As Outlook.attachment
Dim itm As Outlook.MailItem
Dim dateFormat
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yymmdd ")

saveFolder = "C:\temp"
For Each itm In ActiveExplorer.Selection
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
     If objAtt.Size > 5200 Then
       objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
        End If
    Next objAtt
Next itm
End Sub
```

Comment: is this not working? It is unclear what you are trying to ask.

Comment: the script works on an email when it is selected, I wanted to change it to work automatically on incoming mail (using an outlook rule) without having to select the email

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass an item as a parameter. So, the code should look like the following one:

```
Public Sub script(itm as Outlook.MailItem)
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.attachment
    Dim dateFormat

    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yymmdd ")
    saveFolder = "D:\temp"
    For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
       If objAtt.Size > 5200 Then
          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
          Set objAtt = Nothing
       End If
    Next objAtt
End Sub
```

And don't save attachments on the C: drive, it requires admin privileges on the latest Windows OS. Choose another drive/folder.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can use a rule for this.  I think you will need to hook up an Outlook event.  To do this you would use code like the following;

```
Private WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()

   Dim olApp As Outlook.Application 
   Dim objNS As Outlook.NameSpace 
   Set olApp = Outlook.Application 
   Set objNS = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI") 
   ' this is for your local Inbox - if you have more inboxes you need to set it for each one
   Set olItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items

End Sub

'You can add this because you used "WithEvents" to declare olItems
Private Sub olItems_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) 

  Dim olMailItem As Outlook.MailItem
 'this event will fire for all items so you need to make sure you have a mail item.
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set olMailItem = item 
    Dim saveFolder As String
    Dim objAtt As Outlook.attachment
    Dim dateFormat
    dateFormat = Format(Now, "yymmdd ")
    saveFolder = "D:\temp"

    For Each objAtt In olMailItem.Attachments
      If objAtt.Size > 5200 Then
        objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & dateFormat & objAtt.DisplayName
        Set objAtt = Nothing
      End If
    Next objAtt    
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Although ItemAdd is superior to rules this simple, frequently asked about code morphs between standalone and runascript format. Each asker wanting the other format. Eugene Astafiev has answered this.